# При использовании ProxyPass, страница server-status не отображается

Tags: apache

Не отображается страница server-status

```
<VirtualHost _default_:8080>
        ServerName      Unknown
        ServerAlias     Unknown
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule / - [R=403]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName      mysite
ServerAlias    localhost mysite 127.0.0.1
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
    <Proxy balancer://ajp-cluster>
        BalancerMember ajp://192.168.42.12:8009 route=node1
        BalancerMember ajp://192.168.42.18:8009 route=node2
        ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
        ProxyPass balancer://ajp-cluster/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

После удаления

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass balancer://ajp-zags-cluster/
</Location>
```

server-status работает, но получается не проксируются другие страницы на ноды. Добавлял

```
   ProxyPass /server-status !
```

вместо ошибка 404, выходит 403, будто мой адрес не разрешен, хотя Location находится выше

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.42.20 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Что не так я делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт. Нашел ответ решение

```
<Location /server-status>
    ProxyPass !
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.42.20 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

внутри VirtualHost, внешне для всех портов почему то не берет. Наверное не понимает почему причем тут ProxyPass !, тогда как самого Proxy нет